# Dealing with quoted strings in .ini files (php and perl)

Tags: php, perl, ini

I am trying to write a config.ini file which will be used with both PHP and perl code.  Some of the values in the file include punctuation characters such as semi-colons, so I've surrounded these values with quotation marks as per the recommendation on PHP's parse_ini_file() documentation page.

As you'd expect, then, parse_ini_file() handles these values just fine.

Unfortunately, when I try to read the ini file with perl's Config::IniFiles module, the values are surrounded by those extra quotation marks.

Of course I could just trim out the quotation marks in perl, but that seems like a silly hack.  I'm curious what the correct way to handle this is.

Comment: I would consider using [`Perl YAML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod) and [`Php YAML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.yaml.php) instead, as their specs might be more likely to match.

Comment: Try Config::INI instead.

Comment: I don't see much of a difference between using an off-the-shelf module that does what you want and creating your own module and class that extends the class that doesn't quite do what you want, and taking this value and doing what you want, and then using *that* module instead of the CPAN module. That's not a "silly hack" if done right.

Comment: @hobbs, Config::INI doesn't handle quotes either.

Comment: @Axeman well, no, if what I want to do is some strange, rare thing.  I just find it hard to believe that I'm the first person who's wanted this.

Comment: @Andrea, it could be that not that many people have wanted to do this. If it's planned from the beginning, it's probably better to use a portable format, like JSON or what people consider its superset, YAML. I take notes in YAML format (combined with markdown). I still think it's reasonable to extend a class to get the behavior that you want, and it's almost like getting it off the shelf.